# Azure DevOps Services in Azure Stack Hub?

Tags: azure-stack, azure-devops-services

I am planning to migrate my work to Azure Stack Hub. Can someone please let me know whether I can use **Azure DevOps Services** in **Azure Stack Hub**. If so please advise me on how to.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your Azure Stack Management URLs are not public, you'll need a Self-hosted Agent on-prem or somewhere that it can see the Azure Stack Management URLs.

The Self-Host agent will need the Azure Stack Environments created for your Azure Stack Hub e.g. AzureStackUser and/or AzureStackAdmin using the appropriate Management URL.

In Azure DevOps, create a New Service Connection for Azure Resource Manager, but make sure the Environment is set to Azure Stack.

The Server Url must be to one of the Management URLs of your Azure Stack that match the Environment you configure. This depends on what you're doing.

For Admin related configuration:

- Use the Admin Management URL e.g. https:///adminmanagement.local.azurestack.external
- Set the Subscription ID and Subscription Name to the Default Subscription on the Azure Stack Hub
- Enter the Service Principal and Connection Details

For User related configuration:

- Use the Management URL e.g. https:///management.local.azurestack.external
- Set the Subscription ID and Subscription Name to the User Subscription defined on the Azure Stack Hub
- Enter the Service Principal and Connection Details

**NOTE:** The Service Principal must have the appropriate Role on either the Default Subscription or the User Subscriptions.

Don't verify the Connection, unless the Management URLs are accessible publically

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I have one more point to clarify. So, we can create CI/CD pipelines in Azure and integrate that with apps in azure stack. But we can't directly  do the deployments in Azure stack. Is that correct?

Comment: You can do deployments to Azure Stack, both application and IaC